# qtcreator does not always refresh my ui when i build

Tags: user-interface, refresh, qt-creator

i noticed that many times i do some modification on a graphical interface created with Qtcreator this is not immediatly applied while building.

even if i call qmake does not work. I have sometimes to close QTcreator reopen it again and build.

Do you know if there is a way to force parsing the .ui file?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its been a while since I used QT but what I often found with problems similar as to what your asking. In the Projects>Build settings: Make shure that shadow-build is unchecked.

Comment: i do not really unedrstand what is this property.
but unchecking that box really solved my problem! :)
Cheers,

Comment: no prob. Shadow-build means that when running it can grab an older version of your project that is already build. Why its there and always seems to get magically switched on, I couldn't say.